# Way to see assigned visual studio shortcuts with given prefix

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a simple way to see assigned shortcuts with given prefix? Something similar to emacs <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>. I can do it in following way, but hope, that there is more simple solution:

- Tools -> Customize -> Keyboard
- In "Press shorcut keys" press given prefix (say <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>)
- In "Shortcut currently used by" combo-box there is a list of assigned shortcuts with given prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wintellect has a [macro that will list all Visual Studio shortcuts](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2005/11/03/charles-petzold-is-right-and-some-code-and-some-profiling-and-some-bsod-debugging.aspx).  Run that and you can do any analysis on the output you like.

Comment: Thank you! Macro may be polished to insert required filtering, but main idea is clear.